# PHP $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] debugging with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have a PHP script where I was trying to track down where an error comes from and I added this:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']
```

the error was kind of sporadic and I could not locate its source.  It just happened again and here are the logs from the server:

```
referer: http://www.comehike.com/hikes/scheduled_hike.php?hike_id=164
```

But when I revisit that page, the error does not happen.

Comment: Ehm, what specific error did occur? And how is it related to the referrer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What was the error? It's probably due to a direct hit where there is no referrer or the user has privacy software that prevents that header from being sent. You should check that it is set before trying to use it.

Comment: I have the php script email me that there was an error.  The issue was a broken query where the $hike_id parameter was not getting recognized. I wasn't sure how to reproduce it so I put the referrer code in there to try to understand how this happens.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to figure out what causes the parameter to be empty.  What do sites do in case the header can not be sent? And why wouldn't the header be sent? It is a security issue?